# How to create UUID in JSNI of the input elements?

Tags: uuid, jsni

How to create UUID in JSNI for each input element. Each time of call the id's of the input elements must change and new entries must be inserted in database with every new form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally succeeded in doing so by getting the values directly in variable by
`fname=a.value;`
where `a` is the input box of jsni and `fname` is the variable where the value is being stored.